# Replacing dynamic content jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a dynamic replace in a string with jQuery. I have read about using wildcards in selectors, but I want it in a string.

Considering this HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">@import url('css/another.css');</style>
<style type="text/css">@import url('css/stylesMQ.css');</style>
```

And I have this function in jQuery:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("MQ.css", "400MQ.css");
        });
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("MQ.css", "800MQ.css");
        });         
    } else {
       $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("MQ.css", "MQ.css");
        });         
    }
}
```

This function is part of an entire jQuery that changes an @imported css depending of screen size.

---

**ERROR**

It works, but when I start playing with the screen size I get something like:

```
@import url('css/styles800800800800400400400400400400400400400400MQ.css');
```

---

I can't figure **how can I tell jQuery to replace also the number**. 
I suppose that I need something like:

```
.replace("styles*MQ.css", "styles400MQ.css");
```

---

**TIPS:**

- I'm not using mediaqueries because my client is Fred Flinstone, he uses IE7 and don't wants pollyfills because the extra loading time and because thinks they're the demon.
- There are other @imported CSS's in the page
- I don't know the entire path for the CSS nor the folder, only the name (that's the reason I want to make replacing instead of write the relative path location of the new CSS.)
- I can change the name of any of these CSS.

Comment: this is related to javascript, not specific to jquery, you should edit your tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.replace("MQ.css", "MQ.css");` try something like

```
.replace(/\d*MQ\.css/, "MQ.css");
.replace(/\d*MQ\.css/, "400MQ.css");
```

Comment: @Arkana there was an issue, fixed

Comment: @downvoter another one!! :) . looks like someone is crazy... still would you mind explaining why

Comment: The DV is mine! Sorry! Because I had thought the code didn't work, but it was my mistake. I tried to remove the DV, but I recklessly press the button twice and now is blocked. :( Please, could you edit the answer (altough dummy edit) to unblock my stupid-foolish vote, please?

Comment: How is called what you used, please, all that slashes and asterisk stuff? (I'm a totally n00b).  I would like to understand better how it works but do not know what to google up. Thank you.

Comment: It is using [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You can search for [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in net

Answer (score 0):

```
$('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().split('/')[0]+"/400MQ.css";
});
```

Comment: Another, more semantic option would be to add a class to the body of the page (.mq400) , and prefix the relevant styles in a single css file with that class (`.mq400 p {/* etc */ }`) 

The advantage is that this way only a single css file needs to be loaded and the change would be instant (as opposed to loading a new css file after the page has loaded and the js has executed).

Comment: This works in this concrete case, but in a large path (like `@import url('folder/css/MQ.css')`) it deletes me almost the entire path...

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$('style:contains("MQ")').text(function (pos, value) {
        return value.replace(/styles(400|)MQ\.css/, "styles800MQ.css");
});
```

same solution changing the expected expression (400, 800, '')